# how to give border only for selected text in an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for which i have no access to change the html.
How can I give border-bottom or text decoration: underline only to thefrontbottoms.com.

```html
<div class="headera">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://thefrontbottoms.com">Back To TheFrontBottoms.com</a></div>
```

Actual Result: border-bottom to **"Back To FrontBottoms.com"**

Expected Result: border-bottom to "Back To **FrontBottoms.com**"

Comment: And you can use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to HTML, this might be the best thing you could do

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 238);
  width: 145px;
  top: 24px;
  left: 68px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headera">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://thefrontbottoms.com">Back To TheFrontBottoms.com</a></div>
```

Comment: LOL, I took too long to set that border in right position. You were quick! And @Parthee, I second this. I guess this is the best you can do if you can't do anything with HTML or JS.

Comment: I added a jQuery version too

Comment: osm... this works perfect and i had an issue with tablet narrower and managed with media query. cool.

Comment: Check the jQuery version too, that one is the correct way to do it

Comment: And don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer if you think it is correct

Comment: @Parthee If it works perfect, you might want to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.headera {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 195px;
}
    .headera a:after
    {
background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-right: 1px none white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    right: 0;
    width: 139px;
}
```

Use this

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with little jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').html("Back To <span>TheFrontBottoms.com</span>");
});
```

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headera">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://thefrontbottoms.com">Back To TheFrontBottoms.com</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this instead:

```
<style>
  .headera a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .headera a span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    /* or */
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

<div class="headera">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://thefrontbottoms.com">Back To <span>TheFrontBottoms.com</span></a></div>
```

Comment: HTML can't be accessed!

Comment: html cannot be accessed (yes)

Comment: ok. well then if you can't access the HTML, your only other option is with JavaScript. Can you inject scripting into the page? If not, you're SOL in this case :(

Comment: This can be done with a hack in CSS. Check my answer

Comment: I get downvoted because @Patel puts in that HTML can't be accessed *after the fact*??